# "Seventy-seven head of cattle"? Singular or plural noun after numbers

Tags: numerals

In another translation from Chinese to English, I met this part -

> Seventy-seven head of cattle.

As far as I remember English grammar, **head** in this case can be used instead of **heads** only if we say something like

> Seventy-one head of cattle.

However, in any other case, we have to use **heads**, and the correct phrase would be

> Seventy-seven heads of cattle.

Am I right?

Comment: No, you're wrong. There's no difference between your two examples. "Head" is a plural-only noun -- there is no *"x heads of cattle".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head when used as a unit of count for live animals has singular form ("head"). Thus, if you wish to discuss your herd of cows, you might say "I have seventy-one head of cattle on my farm".

> a person or animal when considered as a unit

If you wish to discuss the severed heads of animals, e.g. in a butchery or meat context, you would use the plural form, and might well say "I have sold seventy-one cow heads (or cows' heads) to the dog food company". In the latter situation, a native speaker would be unlikely to speak of "heads of cattle".

> the part of the body above the neck where the eyes, nose,
>   mouth, ears, and brain are:

[Head (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/head)

Answer (score 1):

> *Seventy-seven head of cattle.*

"Head" is an uninflected plural-only noun, i.e. it is not morphologically marked as a plural.  Here the quantificational noun construction avoids the problem that arises with "cattle", where we can use high round numerals like "a thousand cattle", but not low numerals like *"seven cattle".